# How can I display UTF-8 characters in knitr chunk outputs?

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, r-markdown, knitr

In short, my issue is that I have custom classes which print nicely in the RStudio console, but look horrible in R Markdown since special characters are shown as UTF8 codes. As an example, in the RStudio console you get this behaviour:

```
cat("\U2713")
#> ✓
```

Whereas, rendering this using `knitr` you get:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
cat("\U2713")
```
````

[image: knitr example output]
Is there a way to effectively get the same behaviour in `knitr` chunk outputs as in the RStudio console? Including the inline code `` `r "\U2713"` `` in markdown documents correctly renders as '✓', so I feel like this should be easy to achieve.